# Run Server Symfony 4

Tags: cmd, server, composer-php, symfony4, wampserver

I start developp an application web with framework symfony4  , I download composer

and for the  server I use wampserver , and I alraeady hava php 7 on my pc.

i put composer in the path( variable system)

After creating my project with cmd, I Want to run my server

--> I write the cmd line: 
             php bin/console server:run

```
but it show a message " Command:"server:run" is not defined
```

Someone have a idea ??  Explain to me what happen , and what should I  do ??

Answer (score 0):

WAMP is not a sever. WAMP means Windows Apache MySql Php. WAMP is an environement that contain an Apache server that include PHP module (to parse php files), and a MySql server. They are already setup to works together.

I don't know what you mean by : "I already have PHP 7" but the point is that when you have to use php from command line, you must use php.exe from WAMP (and the right version between 5.6, 7.0, 7.1, 7.3)

So "php bin/console" should be somethings like "c:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.5\php.exe bin/console"

About that "php bin/console server:run" :

If you use WAMP that line seems useless to me. You have to start WAMP and then Apache server will be run. So you don't need to make it run with a command line.

When WAMP is started you can check services status by left-click on the WAMP Icon in the Windows taskbar. Maybe you have to configure Windows taskbar to display WAMP icon in.

Last point : to make your application working in WAMP you have to configure an Apache virtual host (vhost). Left-click on WAMP icon -> Your VirtualHosts -> Manage VirtualHost.